# error on decryption while loop

Tags: java, encryption

What should happen is that entering -2 when asked to 'enter the numbers to decrpyt' will end the while loop and after which result2 (the decrypted word) prints. Instead -2 produces an error 
'java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2'

How do I bypass this?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Decrypt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc;
        int  result, input2, num, end = -2;
        String word, sourcetext, answer, encrypt = "1", decrypt="2";

        char input, result2;
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("please enter sourcetext");
        sourcetext = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Would you like to 1: encrypt, or 2: decrypt?");
        answer = sc.next();

        System.out.println("please enter numbers to decrypt"); 
        while (answer.equals(decrypt)) {

            num = sc.nextInt();                   // number to decrypt
            result2 = sourcetext.charAt(num);     // num decrypted

            if (num <= end) {                     // int end = -2

                System.out.print(result2);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just check whether the entered number, num, is below zero before the line 'result2 = sourcetext.charAt(num);' or use try..catch

Comment: Still throwing an exception  'java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2'

Comment: You cant have -2 as index of a string

Answer (score 0):

When -2 is entered, it is passing that to `charAt` which throws the exception because there is no -2 index in the string. You should move the `if (num <= end)` block to the start of the while loop and put the rest into an `else` block.

Like this:

```
if (num <= end){                     
    System.out.print(result2);
} else {
    num = sc.nextInt();                   // number to decrypt
    result2 = sourcetext.charAt(num);     // num decrypted
}
```

Comment: What will be the value of result2?

Comment: The problem with that is num and result2 will not be initialised and will throw an error at the if statement. Rakesh, result2 will show the numbers that the user inputs decrypted using the positions of the letters in the source text.

Comment: @Button Then you either need to give `result2` a default value of some sort or rework your logic. The point is you can't have a negative index in the `charAt` method, which is why you were getting an error. Knowing this now, you should be able to re-work your code to avoid this. I'm not going to rewrite your program for you.